# Accept native component properties as props and have custom ones with a TypeScript interface in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have this `AppText` component where I want to use a `Props` interface while having the ability to accept other props fields that I can consume with a `spread operator`. But I'm getting this error:

```
Type '{ children: string; accessible: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.Property 'accessible' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

AppText:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { colors } from "../utils/config";

interface Props {
  fontSize?: number;
  color?: string;
}
const AppText: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  fontSize = 16,
  color = colors.black,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  return (
    <Text {...restProps} style={{ color: color, fontSize: fontSize }}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default AppText;
```

How I am using it:

```
<AppText accessible>Not a member yet ?</AppText>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to redefine `Props`, I assume `TextProps` can be imported from `react-native`, like so:

```typescript
interface Props extends TextProps {
  fontSize?: number;
  color?: string;
}
```

This adds `TextProps` to your properties, the spread operator should understand what elements are left over.